# Как сделать прыжок как в hollow knight?

Tags: c#, unity3d

addForce дает не тот результат, который нужен. Scale гравитации тоже не помогает особо. Попробовал много способов с туториалов с ютуба, но после них в процессе прыжка персонаж становился дерганным что ли. Думаю, это происходило из-за ограничения скорости падения, реализованного так, что если скорость больше заданной, то сделаем равной заданной. Как реализовать это аккуратнее, при этом всё ещё используя физику rigit body, не очень понятно.

Сам прыжок в "пустом рыцаре" реализован примерно так: пока кнопка пробела зажата, персонаж летит вверх с фиксированной скоростью. Когда отжимается, с той же скоростью вниз. При этом между двумя этими состояниями очень быстрый переход, но плавный. Как будто гравитация в 10 раз заскейлена. Ну и если сделать примерно описанную физику и ограничить скорость, то персонаж начинает дергаться.

Comment: Я не знаю ответа на ваш вопрос, но добавьте тег Unity3D, потому что так называется программа. Если вы добавили ТОЛЬКО тег unity2d, то ваш вопрос заметит меньшее количество людей.

Comment: @SLiver добавил, спасибо

Comment: Потому что нужно уже всем давно проголосовать за то что `unity2d` это синоним `unity3d`, как уже дано сделали на английском стеке. Предложение висит, голосов 0, а нужно всего ничего.

Comment: @Yaroslav Unity на русском стэке перестал подавать признаки жизни еще года полтора назад, предложение банально некому принимать.

Comment: @Yaroslav https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/synonyms проголосовал

Comment: Ещё трое и сделаем доброе дело.

Comment: @Yaroslav Нужно поднять на мете. Я, например, давно за это, а то, что такое голосование есть, даже не знал. Ибо фильтрация стоит на unity3d, и 2D-шники проходят мимо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать манипулируя `RigidBody.velocity`.

Пока зажата кнопка прыжка или не кончился ограничивающий таймер поддерживать фиксированное значение `.velocity.y`.

Comment: Я понимаю что так можно сделать, и делал. Я в вопросе написал, что примерно нужной физики я добился. Но проблема которая появилась - с ограничением скорости падения. Если просто в fixedupdate уменьшать скорость, если она превышает какое-то значение, то персонаж дёргается. И как это исправить я и хочу узнать. Извините, если не правильно сформулировал вопрос

Comment: Код в вопрос добавь.